# delete data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am unable to delete the data in codeiginter I am new to it so please help me....

my code for the view page is

```
<?php
   foreach($item as $field)
   {
   ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $field->facility_id; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $field->facility_name; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $field->facility_desc; ?></td>
       <td>Edit</a></td>
       <td><?php echo anchor('http://localhost/Alaris_Health/index.php/admin_controller/delete_facility','Delete',$field->facility_id);?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php
}
?>
```

and my code for the controller is

```
function delete_facility($fac_id)
{
    $this->load->model('Admin_model');
    $this->Admin_model->remove_facility($fac_id);
    $this->load->view('facility_view',$data);
}
```

and code for model is

```
function remove_facility($fac_id)
{
     $this->db->delete('admin_facility_code', array('facility_id' => $fac_id)); 
}
```

Comment: Have you load uri,html libraries..??

Comment: jsut enable profiler you will get error if any

Comment: whats the error? If there is no error are you able to get fac_id in your controller?

Comment: where this $data come from in your Controller last line ?

Comment: There are so many errors like  Missing argument 1 for Admin_controller::delete_facility() ,   Undefined variable: fac_id,Undefined variable: data,Undefined variable: item etc    is that my syntax for anchor for passing the value is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
<?php echo anchor('http://localhost/Alaris_Health/index.php/admin_controller/delete_facility','Delete',$field->facility_id);?>

function delete_facility($fac_id)
{
    $this->load->model('Admin_model');
    $this->Admin_model->remove_facility($fac_id);
    $this->load->view('facility_view',$data);
}
```

Try this :

```
<?php echo anchor('http://localhost/Alaris_Health/index.php/admin_controller/delete_facility/'.$field->facility_id.'','Delete','');?>

function delete_facility()
{
    $this->load->model('Admin_model');
    $fac_id = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $this->Admin_model->remove_facility($fac_id);
    $this->load->view('facility_view');
}
```

Comment: now again  i got two errors Undefined variable: item and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I used those for fetching the data

Comment: Instead of this `$this->load->view('facility_view');` redirect to the listing page again, because you are not assigning that data again to facility_view page, or load the same data again and assign it again after deleting the record then there will be no error.

Comment: Are you getting `$fac_id` in model?

Comment: You can try $this->uri->segment(4); instead of $this->uri->segment(5);

Answer (score 0):

try using [`site_url()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)..... and you need to pass the id in url

> You are encouraged to use this function any time you need to generate a local URL so that your pages become more portable in the event your URL changes.

**updated**

```
....
<td><?php echo anchor(site_url('admin_controller/delete_facility/'.$field->facility_id),'Delete','id="'.$field->facility_id).'"'?></td>
```

Comment: I also Tried This one bipen but still getting errors I think there is some problem with double and single quotes